# Using formattingAdd for custom <pre> adding multiple <pre> tags

Tags: redactor

Using Redactor in CraftCMS I've added the following to the redactor/Standard.json file:

```
{
    "formattingAdd": {
        "pre-php": {
            "title": "PHP Code",
            "args": ["pre", "class", "language-php", "add"]
        }
    }
}
```

The option appears in the `format` menu as expected.

The problem: When applying this new format, multiple <pre></pre> tags are created (one set per block of code), where-as the default Format->Code option properly creates a single <pre></pre> around the selected blocks of code.

Is there a way to get redactor to properly add <pre></pre> tags with a custom class name?

Formatted with built-in Format->Code option:
[image]

Formatted with custom format option:
[image]